# NOTEPAD++ Change line with variable inside

Tags: replace, notepad++, notepad, replaceall

How to change big file like

GSKPP / 3520767 / 1 / 30300

to

GSKPP / 1 / 30300

if `3520767`  is variable?

**EDIT:**

Comment: What do you mean by "if 3520767 is variable" ? "Any white-space-free string"? Or "any number"? Or "any decimal number"? Or "any positive decimal number"? Or "the content of an environment variable"?

Comment: @Yunnosch this value "3520767" will be changed, I have tried to use *, but no luck

Comment: Is the number to change allways between two slashes?

Comment: Could you choose one of the more precise descriptions I offered?

Comment: @Toto have update question, to make it easier, yes this number will be allways different.

Comment: @Yunnosch if will be could be 7 numbers or 1 letter at the biggining and 6 number (b123456). Spaces are exactly the same as I post it.

Comment: That's not what I asked, I'd like to know if the number is allways between `/ ` and ` /`

Comment: The possible letter invalidates both currently existing answers. You know, I have a reason for asking about more precise descriptions.

Comment: Could you give more details about the text around the string to replace? Wil it be always "GSKPP / " on the left and " / 1 / 30300" on the right?

Comment: Try to answer one of the following two questions "How can I recognise what you want to delete, without risk of deleting something different but similar looking?"  or "Where exactly is that what should be deleted, how does the text look before and after it?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?\K/\s+[a-z]?\d+`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
.*?         : 0 or more any character, not greedy
\K          : forget all we have seen until now
/           : slash
\s+         : 1 or more space
[a-z]?      : an optional letter
\d+         : 1 or more digits
```

Comment: This was accepted, to my surprise because I think it won't find OPs "or 1 letter at the biggining and 6 number (b123456)". And it has quite a high risk of deleteing other content.

Answer (score 0):

`CTRL`+`H`: Opens search and replace window

Search: `GSKPP / [a-zA-z]{0,1}[0-9]* / 1 / 30300`
Replace: `GSKPP / 1 / 30300`

Regular Expressions do have to be activated on bottom of the Search and Replace Window!

`[0-9]*` as regular expression means: search for any number of digits between 0 and 9.

`[a-zA-z]{0,1}` means: zero or one small or large letter.

The search entry before and after the regex is treated as constant.

This gives for the following input:

```
GSKPP / 3520767 / 1 / 30300
GSKPP / b25525 / 1 / 30300
GSKPP / Z2 / 1 / 30300
```

the output:

```
GSKPP / 1 / 30300
GSKPP / 1 / 30300
GSKPP / 1 / 30300
```

Comment: Won't find OPs "or 1 letter at the biggining and 6 number (b123456)".

Comment: Fixed it too... good you asked for further information, but haven't read this when posting first.